# Chart Web Part and lookup fields

Tags: lookup-column, chart-web-part, chart

How can I make my Chart Web Part look good when I use it with lookup fields?

The issue I have is that the chart displays the field id along with its value. For example, it displays "2;#Bing" when I'd like to see only "Bing".

Answer (score 1):

you can use xpath to do that, for example 
/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[substring-after(@field., '#')

But that has to be done in a dataview that displays a content source in your page

Another way would be to use javascript or jquery to split the text of a paragraph or a div for example with a specific id
Hope that helps

Tolis

Answer (score 1):

I have mention how to split values in your [chart web part](http://www.apptha.com/sharepoint/chart-web-part),

```
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["YourItemname"].ToString()) && item["yourItemname"].ToString().Contains("#"))

   item["YourItemname"] = item["YourItemname"].ToString().Split('#')[1];
}
```

Hope this answers is very helpful for you.